# Keep only specific characters from one text file and write these in a new text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to select a specific character. Say the file `old.txt` contains `xxXXyyaasdyyYY`. From that file only `X` and `Y` should be retained and written to `new.txt`.
What is wrong in below code?

```
in_file = open("old.txt", "r")
out_file = open("new.txt","w")
for line in in_file:
    out_file.write(line.upper())
in_file.close()
out_file.close()
```

Comment: I gotta ask why?  This doesn't seem very intuitive.  Are you trying to count the number of instances certain characters are found? or what?  I think a few more details of what you're actually trying to do here are in order.

Comment: BTW you should use: `with open('old.txt', 'r') as in_file, open('new.txt', 'w') as out_file:`  instead of explicitly opening and closing the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to select characters, you may read one character at a time.

```
from collections import defaultdict

specific_characters = ['X', 'Y']
counter_dict = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

with open("old.txt", "r") as in_file, open("new.txt","a") as out_file:
  while True:
    c = in_file.read(1)
    if not c:
      break
    if c in specific_characters:
      out_file.write(c)
      counter_dict[c] += 1

# printing just X and Y for your specific case. 
# the counter will have count of any characters from the specific_characters list.

print "Count of X: ", counter_dict['X']
print "Count of Y: ", counter_dict['Y']
```

Comment: @Chris Gruber: I have updated the code with counter. Please check now.

Answer (score 1):

```
in_file = open("old.txt", "r")
out_file = open("new.txt","w")
for line in in_file:
  for letter in line:
    if (letter == 'X') | (letter == 'Y'):
        out_file.write(letter.upper())
in_file.close()
out_file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks sam, forgot the quotes.

Comment: Also, I think `X` and `Y` are just an example. Those could be any strings.

Comment: Thanks. That works, how to count how many "X" and "Y" values. also want to get the ratio.

Comment: you mean `or`, not `|`. `|` is bitwise OR in Python. Regardless, neither is as quick as `letter_whitelist = {"X", "Y"}; if letter in letter_whitelist:`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a whitelist `set` and a context manager (using the `with` keyword) to make this much more idiomatic.

```
whitelist = {"X", "Y"}

with open('old.txt') as in_file,
        open('new.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        for letter in line:
            if letter in whitelist:
                out_file.write(letter)  # no need to uppercase here
# no need to close either, since we're using the with statement
```